# When do you omit a liaison?

Tags: oral, liaisons

I have seen that there are cases where a word will end in a consonant and the next will begin in a vowel, yet it is correct to *not* use a liaison. It is apparently not as simple as French learners are first taught.

How can you know whether or not two words should be linked by a liaison when spoken aloud, assuming the first ends in a consonant and the second begins with a vowel?

I have even heard of cases where it depends on the speaker's intended meaning, and I find this very unclear.

Comment: There are three categories: required, optional, and impossible. Besides other questions (see the "related" panel to the right), these are detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)#Constraints_on_liaison) on English Wikipedia and even better [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Cat%C3%A9gories) on French Wikipedia. If you're still unclear on them I can try to boil some of the rules from those sources down into an answer for this thread but it probably won't happen today.

Comment: Thanks, great resource! Not sure if I should delete the question based on someone having pointed out a resource that addresses it?